# Removing form array element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, forms

I have a form which has same products but with different attributes.
The form looks something similar to this:

```
<form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> Line-1 </td>
        <td> <input type='text' name='ítem[1][Size]'</td>
        <td> <input type='text' name='ítem[1][Color]'</td>
        <td> <input type='text' name='ítem[1][Price]'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Line-2 </td>
        <td> <input type='text' name='ítem[2][Size]'</td>
        <td> <input type='text' name='ítem[2][Color]'</td>
        <td> <input type='text' name='ítem[2][Price]'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Line-3 </td>
        <td> <input type='text' name='ítem[3][Size]'</td>
        <td> <input type='text' name='ítem[3][Color]'</td>
        <td> <input type='text' name='ítem[3][Price]'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Line-4 </td>
        <td> <input type='text' name='ítem[4][Size]'</td>
        <td> <input type='text' name='ítem[4][Color]'</td>
        <td> <input type='text' name='ítem[4][Price]'</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

PHP Sample Code:

```
for($i = 0;$i < count($_POST);$i++){
    var_dump($_POST[$i]);
}
```

Error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\testing.php on line 5
```

If I was to remove item[2] dynamically using js, on submit php would throw an error because it cant find number 2. How could go about this?

Perhaps I'm not doing it right?

Comment: Can you show us _What are you doing_ here? It's hard to tell anything without code

Comment: We need to see what your PHP Code is doing. Please edit and post your PHP form handler. What is the error you're getting.

Comment: Because you are violating array indexes. And please put your error here?

Comment: I'm not sure what other code i could write in. I have a form, which gets processed in php using post, In php, if I would write foreach(), it would throw an error because it cant find number 2 so it cant carry on. I will try adding snippet

Comment: @Vilius.. ad your PHP file code.

Comment: @Vilius I'm assuming you're using `for` not `foreach`. `foreach` will never produce an undefined index error.

Comment: You are using for or foreach? because Mike is right.Foreach is not going to produce any error

Comment: instead of doing `for($i=1;$i<=(count($_POST['item']));$i++)` you could do `foreach($_POST['item'] as $i=>$value)`

Comment: Use foreach rather than for

Comment: Also, you aren't closing your `<input>` tags. Hopefully that's just a typo from posting your code here...

Comment: your inputs are named `item[]`, so your `$_POST[$i]` is invalid as it should be `$_POST['item'][$i]`

Comment: @mopo922 sorry that was a typo. Another question how would i go about re-changing row numbers once I deleted row number 2?

Answer (score 5):

In your PHP Code, use `foreach` as has been suggested:

```
foreach($_POST['item'] as $item){
    echo $item['Size'] . "<br />";
    echo $item['Color'] . "<br />";
    echo $item['Price'] . "<br />";
    echo "<hr />"
}
```

**EDIT:**

> Another question how would i go about re-changing row numbers once I
>   deleted row number 2?

This is done in JS or JQuery. Something like:

```
var i = 1;
$.each($("tr"), function(){
  $(this).next("input[name*='Size']").attr("name", "item[" + i + "][Size]");
  $(this).next("input[name*='Color']").attr("name", "item[" + i + "][Color]");
  $(this).next("input[name*='Price']").attr("name", "item[" + i + "][Price]");
  i++;
});
```